# Prevent search bar for Issuu Find Widget from being hidden

Tags: search, widget, issuu

I'm trying to make the search bar feature used in Issuu display at all times. I have been experimenting with chrome dev tools, and it seems that when I remove the class "find-widget--hidden," I get the desired functionality.

However, Issuu uses an embedded iframe to share the content and I have not had any success making any changes since, from what I understand, I cannot alter the contents of an iframe loaded from a different domain.

I there any other way to prevent the search bar from disappearing?

This is a close example of what I am working with:

https://issuu.com/stylesamplemagazine/docs/stylesamplemag_9